# @Page style is not working in IE and Firefox

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox

I have following style for page printing (Ctrl+p).

```
@page {
    size: A4 landscape;
}
```

It works in the chrome only. It does not work in FF & IE.

IE version: 11
FF version: 38.0.1

Comment: Try with:@media print {  }

Comment: Thanks! solved using `@media print`. Is that mean `@page` does not work in IE & FF.

Comment: Not sure about that..but would like to mention that @page was introduced in CSS2..while print is introduced in CSS3...so maybe its just the browser support based on css version..